# Is it reasonable to use System.currentTimeMillis() in conjunction with System.nanoTime()?

Tags: java, time, timer, nanotime

Here is my modest proposal:

1. When the JVM starts

   1. Call `System.currentTimeMillis()` and store as starting "wall clock" time: 
      `long currentTimeMillis0`.
   2. Call `System.nanoTime()` and store as starting "nano" time: 
      `long nanoTime0`.
2. Throughout the run of the program, store many timestamps using `System.nanoTime()`.

I am well aware the exact value of a nanoTime is useless by itself, but useful when used in the context of a duration: `endNanoTime - beginNanoTime`.

Is it then reasonable, at any nanoTime recorded, to calculate "currentTimeNanos" as:

`(1000L * currentTimeMillis0) + (anyNanoTime - nanoTime0)`?

Comment: Yes... in a single JVM instance this will be a good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I use milli-second and nano-time is I use nano-time for calculating small differences in time and a milli-second timer once at the start to give context.

Note: it is possible to use nano-time between machine if you have a continuous stream of timings. i.e. you can estimate the best timings between them and detect outliers (even if you don't know the absolute difference)  I use this class to help estimate the [RunningMinimum](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/main/java/net/openhft/lang/testing/RunningMinimum.java)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to combine start/end times, both in millis and nano. For example:

```
long startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;
long startTimeNano = System.nanoTime();
... // do some work
long currentTimeNano = (System.currentTimeMillis()*1000 - startTimeMillis) + (System.nanoTime() - startTimeNano);
```

For more information, the official javadoc of the nanoTime method:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

Comment: It appears to be a complicated way to calculate the nano-time difference plus 0.1% with a slight error. Can you explain how this is better than nano time alone?

Comment: The scale between milli and nano is 1000000 not 1000. But in Java you can't do anything useful with sub-milli instant (as opposed to duration) anyway.